# Deadlock in Entity Framework Code First v 4.3

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a database that I am updating via an EF code first model.  This database contains one "parent" table and 10 or 12 "child" tables.  There is a foreign key relationship between the parent and child table.

Initially, when I would want to create a record in a child table, I would use EF to create the parent row, get the primary key, and use EF to create the child row, using the primary key as the foreign key in the child.

Recently I re-factored my model to use TPT inheritance.  So now I have a base class (corresponding to my base table) and child classes (corresponding to my child table).  So now if I want to create a child record, I create an object of the child type, populate all required fields and use the context to save.  I am assuming (because it's logical) that the SQL that EF generates does pretty much the same thing I was doing manually:

1. Create parent record.
2. Get primary key of new parent record
3. Create child record

The problem is now, with using TPT inheritance, I am getting deadlock errors.  5-10 times a day I'll get a deadlock error when trying to create entries in this database.  This database is a log database for a website, so I would say 90% of the operations are writes.  I use it to log activity on the site.

I can easily make the error happen very frequently if I put enough load on the test instance of my website.  I am in the process of trying to get a SQL trace from my DBAs as I do not have the ability to do this myself (even in test).  I know that will be most helpful and when I get that I will post it back here, but my first question is, could there be anything **obvious** that I'm doing wrong?  I researched this online, trying to find out what type of concurrency EF uses, and the responses were mixed. Some say it uses the SQL server default (read committed), while others said that since it wraps it's queries in a TransactionScope object, it uses the default TransactionScope isolation level, which is Serializable.

Can anybody say for sure what isolation level is used, and/or what SQL is generated when you create an entity that is part of a TPT inheritance tree?

Thanks.

**EDIT**
So in response to @usr's suggestion from the comments on my original post, I tried wrapping my save in a transaction scope using ReadCommitted level, like this

```
TransactionOptions options = new TransactionOptions();
options.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
using (TransactionScope scope = new     TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, options))
{
    retVal = AuditEventContext.SaveChanges();
    scope.Complete();
}
```

I still get the same deadlock error.  I'm in the process of obtaining a SQL trace from my DBAs.

To put some more context around this application, I will add that my context (AuditEventContext in the code above) is being used by an MVC application.  Each controller gets it's own instance of the AuditEventContext, so I have multiple contexts in multiple threads updating the same database.  I'm sure that is what's causing the deadlock, I just don't really understand why, especially since my original code was mimicking what I assume EF is doing for the inheritance based inserts.

**Edit #2 in response to questions below**

There are other applications that read this data, but I can make this error happen when I know that nothing is reading.  I throw 50 or so users at my website all at once, and this happens almost right away.  Luckily we don't have 50 users on our site at the same time, yet :)  We are not inserting many rows.  This is an auditing database, so we write "audit events" throughout our site, i.e. page requests, accepting legal terms, logging off, etc.  So the inserts are very small.  The context exists for the life of the controller, so it is possible that the same context can be used to insert multiple events, but each transaction is small. I would hope we are not generating duplicate keys because the key on the parent table is an auto generated integer identity.  It's SQL server's job to govern that.  The parent table has 4 indices on it with ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS=ON and ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS=ON.  I did not set these, I just left the SQL defaults.  The indices also have IGNORE_DUP_KEY=OFF

@RuneG, the context is generated by Unity (dependency injection).  I'm not directly creating it.  I am calling Dispose, however, I am calling Dispose when the controller that owns the context is disposed of, not immediately after calling save changes like I would if I were creating the context with a using statement.  Could this be triggering the problem?  Using the same context for multiple updates?

**Edit #3 - Deadlocking SQL**

Finally got a SQL trace.  Here is an example of deadlocking SQL

```
exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[PFIAccessLog]([AuditEventID], [Screen],     [PolicyNumber], [CoverageSequence], [PersonTypeID])
values (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4)
select [PFIAccessLogID]
from [dbo].[PFIAccessLog]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [AuditEventID] = @0',N'@0 bigint,@1 nvarchar(100),@2   nvarchar(50),@3 nvarchar(50),@4    int',@0=2035631,@1=N'ContractList',@2=N'220001197',@3=N'1',@4=1
```

and

```
exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[PFIAccessLog]([AuditEventID], [Screen],     [PolicyNumber], [CoverageSequence], [PersonTypeID])
values (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4)
select [PFIAccessLogID]
from [dbo].[PFIAccessLog]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [AuditEventID] = @0',N'@0 bigint,@1 nvarchar(100),@2     nvarchar(50),@3 nvarchar(50),@4     int',@0=2035630,@1=N'ContractList',@2=N'220001197',@3=N'1',@4=1
```

PFIAccessLog is one of the child tables in my TPT hierarchy.

**Edit 4**

OK, so now my code is this, and I'm still getting deadlocks:

```
TransactionOptions options = new TransactionOptions();
options.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
using (TransactionScope scope = new     TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, options))
{
    context.Database.Connection.Open();
    context.Database.Connection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current);
    retVal = context.SaveChanges();
    scope.Complete();
}
```

I also made a change in the code to create a new context each time I write, instead of sharing the context for the life of an MVC controller (which could be multiple writes).

**Edit #5**

OK, at the suggestion of @RuneG I set the isolation level to read uncommitted and it fixed the problem.  However, I'm a little nervous about this.  If you look at the example statements that are deadlocking, part of what I'm reading back are primary key values.  If I can read uncommitted data from another transaction, and these keys are autogenerated by the database, isn't it possible that I could get some other records ID when I read back?

Assuming each of those SQL snippets are executing in a transaction, and since they're both 1 write and 1 read to the same table, I'm assuming the deadlock happens like this

Transaction 1 writes it's data.  It obtains and releases an exclusive lock.
Transaction 1 obtains a shared lock for the read.
Transaction 2 obtains a write lock for it's insert.

Bam, deadlock under read committed, right?  Transaction 1 can't continue because there's a write lock.  Transaction 2 can't continue because there's a shared lock to prevent transaction two from writing data Transaction 1 might see as dirty.

So assuming I'm under read uncommitted now.

Transaction 1 writes it's data.
Transaction 1 reads it's data
Transaction 2 writes it's data
Transaction 2 reads it's data.

One of the processes could block the other with a exclusive lock, but there won't be any shared locks obtained.  So my concern is how does the generation of the primary key fit into all of this.  I'm assuming it's generated while there is an exclusive lock on the table so there's no risk of my keys getting "mixed up"?  I really don't care if some other process might read dirty data that ends up getting rolled back.  The keys are my concern.

And further, this is the result of multiple threads running the same sort of SQL statement.  Threads are the requests in my MVC app.  This seems like a standard scenario.  I'm assuming if I make my code thread safe (i.e. only one thread in the code at a time), I can use read committed?

Sorry for being so verbose.  I tend to be when working through a problem :)

Comment: Nothing obvious. Are the writes insert-only? Can you elaborate a little what operations are going on? Can you tun on snapshot isolation for readers? This would take them out of the equation. Any indexed views?

Comment: Yes, the write are insert only.  No updates or deletes.  I'm not 100% positive about what operations are going on.... I need to get a trace for that.  What I'm assuming is that when I save a new child object through EF, I get three operations.  An insert to insert the parent table row, a read to get the ID that was just inserted, and an insert to create the child row with the parent ID as the foreign key.  No indexed views.  I have a feeling there is a read/write deadlock going on between the read of the inserted ID and another transaction trying to write to the parent table.

Comment: OK, serializable is acquiring range locks. This means that not only the inserted rows are x-locked but also adjacent rows are S-locked. That's probably how conflicts arise. Switch down to at least repeatable read (and for inserts-only any isolation level will do, even read committed).

Comment: Thanks for doing the test. Here are some other, more remote possibilities: are you generating duplicate keys? Are you using IGNORE_DUP_KEY? Are there other queries in the system, which are not strictly insert-only and which might conflict with your insert-only transactions? Are some indexes ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS=OFF? Are you inserting very many rows at one (>500 or so)?

Comment: Could you add code that show the complete operation from creating the context to the SaveChanges? Also, could you show examples of your model?

I can't really see this deadlock happening in your EF related code according to your description.

By the way... EF defines a transaction level of type unspecified to SQLConnection which is the underlying.. This causes SqlConnection to use the database default.

Comment: The transaction might not have taken if the entity connection was opened before the transactionscope. Maybe you need to call AuditEventContext.Connection.Enlist(Transaction.Current). I cannot believe EF would not use the specified transaction in this case.; SQL Server does not have a per-database or per-instance default isolation level. If left unspecified the connection reuses the isolation level of some random other connection on the pool.

Comment: Ok thanks for the update. Can you try doing a `AuditEventContext.Connection.Open(); AuditEventContext.Connection.Enlist(Transaction.Current)`;` right at the beginning of the transaction scope? Reason: My number one suspicion are still serializable range locks. The deadlocking AuditEventIDs (which are probably indexed) are adjacent, so it would make sense.; EF transactions and connections are a bit tricky so I suspect that the transaction scope had no effect.

Comment: Does explicitly specifying batch update make a difference? AuditEventContext.SaveChanges(System.Data.Services.Client.SaveChangesOptions.Batch);

Comment: Using TransactionScope is not neccessary, I would have removed all this code to clean it up. But before this, try the "ugly" solution by using ReadUncomitted instead of ReadComitted and see if that helps you. 

Second, I am not familiar with Unity, I have heard about it, but that's about it. I am a supporter of physically free all context that isn't in use as soon as they are finished with their work. There are many reasons for this. But for me the largest reason is that the context may be quite memory consuming if it has been used to query large amounts of data.

Comment: So, readuncommitted worked, but I do have some concern that I expressed above.  In regards to your comment about Unity, unity is just an object creation mechanism in this case.  It replaces using the new operator.  At first I was letting the context live long enough to possibly execute multiple updates, but I changed the code to make sure the context is created, one update (well, one batch) is run, then it's disposed of.